# Unarchiving encoded data returning nil and incorrect format

Tags: ios, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver, nskeyedunarchiver

I have added category methods to NSUserDefaults to store and retrieve encoded objects (in this case, an NSArray). I am having a problem retrieving the encoded data. Here is my code:

```
- (void)encodeObject:(id<NSCoding>)object forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object requiringSecureCoding:NO error:nil];
    [self setObject:data forKey:key];
    [self synchronize];
}

- (id)decodeObjectForKey:(NSString *)key class:(Class)aClass {
    NSData *data = [self objectForKey:key];
    NSError *error = nil;
    id object = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:aClass fromData:data error:&error];
    NSLog(@"E: %@ %@", error.localizedDescription, object);
    return object;
}
```

Calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] encodeObject:object forKey:key]` should encode the object passed and store it in defaults, and then calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] decodeObjectForKey:key class:aClass` should return the encoded object.

The problem is that `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:]` is returning `nil`, and the error text is logged as `The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.`. The data retrieved using `[self objectForKey:]` is of type `__NSCFData`. I don't know if this is relevant since AFAIK __NSCFData is toll-free bridged to NSData.

Replacing `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:]` with `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:]` solves the problem. The data are stored and retrieved correctly. But this method is now deprecated so I need to move to the more modern method, but cannot identify why it isn't working.

Comment: It's been a while since you've asked this question. Were you able to find the solution by any chance?

Comment: No, I didn't, I had to keep using the deprecated method

Comment: Actually, the answer directly below this, with the extended set of classes, ended up working for me --- eventually. I had to add several classes I hadn't originally considered, and it ended up being the NSURL class that I had been missing. You might also consider adding NSMutableArray, NSMutableDictionary, NSString. I added several classes, got it to work, and then ended up removing classes once it was working. It may also help to inspect the item you want to archive to see all classes that could be included at any level.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem as Mashers with a NSAttributedString and none of the solutions explained here work. More strangely, it affects some files and not others, with no relationship with the creation date. So I'm obliged to use the deprecated method when the unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error: returns an error… Unbelievable

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue. I found that I had to pass in the classes for the objects that were in the NSArray.

```
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithArray:@[
                      [NSArray class],
                      [STUFF_IN_ARRAY class]
                      ]];

NSArray *results = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:set fromData: rawData error: &error];
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Unfortunately this didn't work for me. When I switched to `unarchivedObjectOfClasses: fromData: error:` and passed an NSSet containing `[NSArray class]` and `[MyObject class]`, I had the same problem. I even tried passing the classes for all of the objects' properties into the NSSet, but the same problem occurred. I don't understand what is expected by `unarchivedObjectOfClasses: fromData: error:` and why `unarchiveObjectWithData` was deprecated. The reference page for `unarchivedObjectOfClasses: fromData: error` just says "No overview available" :-/

Comment: I believe this to be the most correct answer. In my situation I archive a custom class. When unarchive, I just have to name my custom class. My custom class archives an `NSString`, an `NSNumber`, and an `NSArray` of yet another custom class. When unarchiving the array, I have to provide a set with `NSArray` and the custom class, as you do in your answer. This last custom class archives `NSDate`, `NSMutableString` and some other NS classes that I don't have to mention anywhere except in the single unarchive call where they are unarchived.

Answer (score 8):

None of the other answers cover this well enough for custom classes (or make it clear enough) so hopefully I can help some people by adding an answer!

If your data represents an archived array of a custom class that has various class properties then it's not enough to just provide the array class and your custom class, you need to provide all the classes that your custom class uses to, e.g.:

```
NSData* data;
NSError* error;
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:
                        [NSSet setWithArray: @[
                             [NSMutableArray class],
                             [CustomClass class],
                             // CustomClass has properties using the following classes:
                             [NSDate class],
                             [NSString class],
                             [NSNumber class],
                             [NSIndexSet class]
                         ]]
                         fromData: data
                         error: &error];
```

Comment: I don't believe you need to specify the classes of the properties of your `CustomClass` class. I'm finding that when unarchiving an `NSArrray` or `NSMutableArray` containing elements that are of a custom class, I only need to create a set containing `NSArray` (or `NSMutableArray`) and my custom class.

Comment: I can confirm the comment by Craig.  I am archiving a set of custom class objeccts.  I set as 'classes' a set of only two classes: NSSet and MyCustomClass. It worked.  But I received a warning that my 'classes' "included NSObject, which is insecure and will be disallowed in the future".  Indeed, MyCustomClass has a property typed as NSObject.  So, apparently -unarchivedObjectOfClasses::: parses the instance variables of custom classes and adds the class of each instance variable to the set of 'classes'.

Comment: After doing more tests, I find that it is only necessary to include collection classes and custom classes in the set passed as `classes`.  It is not necessary to include non-collection non-custom classes.  For example, to unarchive a set of dictionaries of strings, your `classes` should be a set consisting of [NSDictionary class] and [NSSet class].  In Swift, that would be [AnyHashable : Any].self, NSString.self.  Alas, I long for the simple, good old days when we could archive whatever the hell we wanted :(

Answer (score 5):

for inspiration I'm coping my method for unarchiving data from file by [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses: fromData:]...
There is small improvement: you don't need to list all classes in the method call because the most used classes are added automatically in the method body.

```
// MyFileManager.m
- (id)getDataFromFile:(NSString *)file inSubfolder:(NSString *)subfolder dataClasses:(NSArray<Class> *)classes {
    NSString *filePath = [self pathForFile:file subfolder:subfolder];

    NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:filePath];
    NSArray *extendedClasses = [classes arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:@[[NSArray class], [NSMutableArray class], [NSDictionary class], [NSMutableDictionary class], [NSDate class], [NSNumber class]]];

    NSError *unarchivingError;
    id unarchived = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClasses:[NSSet setWithArray:extendedClasses] fromData:data error:&unarchivingError];

    if (unarchivingError) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        return unarchived;
    }
}
```

And here is usage of the  method
// expected unarchived data are in dictionary

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = [FILE_MANAGER getDataFromFile:@"testfile" inSubfolder:nil dataClasses:@[[MyClass class]]];
```

And a small advice. Your "MyClass" must conform the "NSSecureCoding" protocol. And also implement 3 method in you "MyClass"...

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject <NSSecureCoding> // MyClass.h

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *date;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger count;

@end

@implementation MyClass // MyClass.m

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.name = [decoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSString class] forKey:@"name"];
        self.date = [decoder decodeObjectOfClass:[NSDate class] forKey:@"date"];
        self.count = [decoder decodeIntegerForKey:@"count"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.name forKey:@"name"];
    [encoder encodeObject:self.date forKey:@"date"];
    [encoder encodeInteger:self.count forKey:@"count"];
}

+ (BOOL)supportsSecureCoding{
    return YES;
}
```

For those who want to see the helping method "pathForFile" - I use as the main forlder "Library/Application Support" (because of this article **Table 1-3**: [iOS File System Basics](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html))

```
// MyFileManager.m

- (NSString *)pathForFile:(NSString *)file subfolder:(NSString *)subfolder {

    NSString *folderPath = [self storageFolderPathWithSubfolder:subfolder];
    NSString *filePath = [folderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];

    return filePath;
}

- (NSString *)storageFolderPathWithSubfolder:(NSString *)subfolder {

    NSString *storageFolderPath = [self storageFolderPath];

    if (!subfolder.length) {
        return storageFolderPath;
    }

    NSString *subfolderPath = [storageFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:subfolder];

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:subfolderPath]) { //Does directory already exist?
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:subfolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:@{ NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone } error:nil];
    }

    return subfolderPath;
}

- (NSString *)storageFolderPath {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *storageFolderPath = [paths firstObject];

    // create folder if it doesn't exist
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL folderExists = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:storageFolderPath];

    if (!folderExists) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:storageFolderPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:@{ NSFileProtectionKey: NSFileProtectionNone } error:nil];
    }

    return storageFolderPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line should work for you:

```
[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:NSArray.class fromData:data error:&err];
```

Comment: The caller of the category method passes `[NSArray class]` as the `class` parameter, so this is already being sent to `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchivedObjectOfClass:fromData:error:]`.